# What is the correct "returnTo" path for GoAngular $loginUrl running on Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, goinstant, goangular

I'm struggling to set a correct *returnTo* path for 3rd party authentication (i.e. GitHub) in my Cordova/PhoneGap app on an Android 4.3 device. The command to do this in GoAngular is `$goConnectionProvider.$loginUrl(providerName, returnTo)`.

In my dev environment I pass `window.location.href` as my *returnTo* parameter and of course this works fine as the app's location is reported as `http://localhost:[port]/[path]`. Note, I had to whitelist `localhost` in my GoInstant dashboard.

It's worth noting that 3rd party auth also works fine when running through the PhoneGap Developer App on an Android device (since the PhoneGap app basically serves my app over a local IP address, which I also whitelisted).

On Android, the path reported to `window.location.href` is `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/app/`. Therefore, this is the path I supplied to `$goConnectionProvider.$loginUrl`. Unfortunately $goConnection throws an error as this is not an HTTP or HTTPS url.

What should my *returnTo* path be? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the GoInstant Auth API doesn't currently support Cordova/PhoneGap.  The browser views the redirect request as cross-protocol and prevents it.

We've added Cordova/PhoneGap support to the roadmap and I'll update this answer when it becomes available!

Comment: Thanks Slukehart. Appreciate the clarity of your response. Looking forward to hearing more from GoInstant in the future. Cheers.

Comment: No problemo, sorry it wasn't good news. I look forward to updating this once the feature lands :)